# How to create a dictionary of dictionaries...?

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-objects

Imagine I have a database with one or more tables with one more indexes with one or more columns...

I want to create and fill a `Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, List<string>>>` so I can get all indexes of a specific table or all the columns of a specific combination of a table and an index.

Here the tuples with the table, index and column names (sample data)

```
List<Tuple<string, string, string>> tuples = new List<Tuple<string, string, string>>();
tuples.Add(Tuple.Create("T1", "I1", "C1"));
tuples.Add(Tuple.Create("T1", "I1", "C2"));
tuples.Add(Tuple.Create("T1", "I1", "C3"));
tuples.Add(Tuple.Create("T1", "I2", "C1"));
tuples.Add(Tuple.Create("T2", "I1", "C1"));
tuples.Add(Tuple.Create("T3", "I1", "C1"));
tuples.Add(Tuple.Create("T3", "I1", "C2"));
tuples.Add(Tuple.Create("T3", "I2", "C1"));
tuples.Add(Tuple.Create("T3", "I2", "C2"));
tuples.Add(Tuple.Create("T3", "I2", "C3"));
```

Best I could come up with is this:

```
Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, List<string>>> perTI = new Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, List<string>>>();
foreach (var group in tuples.GroupBy(x => Tuple.Create(x.Item1, x.Item2)))
{
    perTI[group.Key.Item1] = new Dictionary<string, List<string>>(){ { group.Key.Item2, group.Select(g => g.Item3).ToList() } };
}
```

Does anyone know a way to do it with 1 LINQ statement?

Comment: If that's working i don't understand why you need to improve it. It's off-topic anyway.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs to http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: What kind of "linq"? LINQ to XML?

Comment: @JohnSaunders: since OP uses a `List<Tuple<string, string, string>>` as source it seems to be Linq-To-Objects.

Comment: It is not a code review question, I just hope that someone can do it in one statement. It is about normal LINQ, I think that is called linq to objects.

Comment: @RayCW: strictly speaking, improving working code doesn't belong to stackoverflow.

Comment: @Tim Schmelter, What do you mean with off topic? The topic is C# and LINQ and dictionaries.

Comment: @RayCW: This means on-topic: http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic This is asking to improve working code which should be asked at [codereview.com](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/) not at stackoverflow: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/253975/be-careful-when-recommending-code-review-to-askers

Comment: @TimSchmelter: I try to train users to _specify_ which LINQ they're using. Different people mean different things when they use "LINQ" without qualification. Remember when everyone who said "LINQ" meant "LINQ to SQL"?

Comment: I don't remember the time when everyone who said LINQ meant LINQ to SQL, I doubt such time existed tbh but I have added a tag 'linq to objects'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All in one line, if that's what you'd like:

```
Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, List<string>>> dict =
    new List<Tuple<string, string, string>>().GroupBy(item => item.Item1)
        .ToDictionary(
            groupedByItem1 => groupedByItem1.Key,
            groupedByItem1 =>
            groupedByItem1.GroupBy(item => item.Item2)
                .ToDictionary(
                    groupedByItem2 => groupedByItem2.Key,
                    groupedByItem2 => groupedByItem2.Select(item => item.Item3).ToList()));
```